# How do I compare offers with different base vs equity components for a tech giant vs a mid-sized startup?

Tags: software-industry, salary, stock

Lets assume you have been extended a couple of job offers that are a mix of salary and equity that you need to compare, coming from different kinds of company:

1. A big tech giant like Microsoft.
2. A kind of mid-sized startup (which might IPO around 4-5 years down the line).

The offers that you receive from both of these companies are almost equivalent in terms of total compensation (base salary + RSU/ESOP). However, they vary by a great extent in terms of the ratio between the two components.

- Microsoft: 63% base, 26% RSU approximately
- Start-up: 83% base, 17% ESOP approximately

PS: % component is based on annual stock amount that is going to be vested. (Eg. 100k USD with vesting period of 4years is considered as 25k USD in the calculation).
Microsoft percentages do not add up to 100% because the remaining part is variable bonus (11%). For the startup, there is no variable bonus, hence its a perfect 100% summation.

Considering factors like role, responsibility, etc. to be equal, how could you determine which offer might be better between the two?

- Should one prioritise the base pay which is going to be a fixed sum
  that you take home?
- Or would you consider Microsoft RSUs to be valuable enough to justify the lesser base pay? How do you compare the value of large-company RSUs vs startup options?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace! Unfortunately [we can't give personal career advice](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/25739) on this site. We can't answer a question that depends so heavily on your own abilities, preferences or circumstances. We *can* answer specific questions on how to handle a workplace situation, accomplish a goal or come to a decision on a practical problem. If you can reword your question to fit those criteria please do so, otherwise your post will likely be closed. Check out the [tour] and [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: Consider rephrasing the question as "How do I compare offers with different base vs equity components" instead of "what should I do"

Comment: @Hilmar, I have made the suggested edits to the question. Please re-open it if it looks okay now.

Comment: @ArjunDatta I'm not a mod, so I can't open it. It still feels more like a "what should I do" then "how do I compare the two offers" question. You can ask for tools and methods to make your own decision, but not for other people to make the decision for you.

Comment: I edited the question to make it openable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All equity is a form of taking lottery tickets as a part of your compensation.  So:

A) you need to make sure the base salary is completely satisfactory to cover your living needs, because it's the only amount you can be guaranteed to get, and

B) you need to figure out what you stand to win with the lottery ticket.

All equity isn’t the same. Stock in an established company like Microsoft is much more reliable than a startup, but you usually stand to gain less (though in the specific case of Microsoft their stock has increased 5x in value over the last 4 years so maybe not!).

For the large company, you should be able to do a quick projection of share value in N years (your vesting periods) based on historical growth and do the math. So if they are giving you 1000 RSUs with 25% vesting each year for four years, you can guesstimate their worth looking at a Microsoft stock chart and deciding if you think the rate of growth will continue to be the same.  If you had 1000 Microsoft RSUs granted around this time in 2016, they would have been worth around (250 * $50) + (250 * $100) + (250 * $150) + (250 * $200) = $125,000 in stock, though if you didn't cash it in immediately upon vesting it'd be 1000 * $210 = $210,000 today.  Minus tax of course, which is levied upon vest.

With a large stable company, you are likely to make around this amount - especially if you don’t mind holding on to the stock an additional year or whatnot if it vests when there is a short term market downturn. (Keep tax in mind as well for your specific situation, it could be more favorable tax-wise).  But assuming you’ve actually done all the math correctly, an estimated return of 26% of your salary here is probably about 26% (in the long term, with no guarantees of course). Keeping in mind that you lose unvested shares if you leave, so if you take the example above and say your "four year average" income from the RSUs is $31,250, if you leave after year one all you really cleared was $12,500.

The worth of a big company RSU is therefore anywhere from "zero to a lot", technically, and how long you plan to stay and how much you think their stock will go up is subjectivity to bake into that estimate. It's also a lot better for growing wealth in the long term that turning into cash short term, so treating it as a long term savings and not money you need to pay your bills is wise.

Startup equity is more in the “magic beans” level of lottery ticket.  It could be nothing and it will certainly be nothing until IPO or other exit. And options work a lot differently from RSUs - RSUs are given to you free and clear; options you have to purchase at the current strike price. For example, I left a startup after a year and I had some vested options; I had to decide whether to write them a check for thousands of dollars to keep those shares or not, with the options being "lose them all and get nothing" or "pay to keep them and keep hoping they eventually pay off."   But depending on your ownership share, how much those shares can be diluted, etc., you could be getting “new house” money out of it. I was at a company that was purchased by a large telecom and all the most early staff got millions out of it. But you have to be in it for the long term and understand it could (and on average, will) be nothing.  You're gambling to possibly make it big. The variance here is much higher than with RSUs for an established company.

Which you pick is simply a matter of your own risk tolerance.  You can't absolutely count on either one, but you are balancing likeliness of higher payoff. Salary is guaranteed(-ish) but doesn't appreciate (you can get raises of course, but salary actually effectively depreciates with inflation and if the market price for your job is rising), RSUs in an enterprise are likely to be reasonably estimated, options in a startup are a shot for the moon. They are the salary equivalent of "sticking it in your savings account", "an very aggressive mutual fund," and "betting it all on random small stocks".

Comment: "quite safe" kinda depends on your definition. It certainly shouldn't go to zero, but there's nothing stopping the stock from falling say 50% in the next few years.

Comment: @hilmar that is exactly what I say in the third paragraph.

Comment: @mxyzplk-SEstopbeingevil, this is pretty informative. Thanks a lot!

Comment: negative comment deleted, Answer has way more detail now